# How to have Entity Framework navigation property query filter in database by default?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext, objectcontext

the dbcontext api seems to set navigation properties to ICollections (for the * ends of associations). The normal way to get queryable objects (like if you wanted a count) seems to be

```
int count = dbcontext.Entry(entry).Collection(c => c.navprop).Query().Count();
```

but that's inconvenient if you want to filter in the db often. More importantly, it's also easy to forget. If someone accidentally says

```
int count = entry.navprop.Count();
```

then it gets all of the data on the server and does the count there, which is slow.

The same thing is true for the EntityCollection type that ObjectContext uses by default.

```
int count = entry.navprop.CreateSourceQuery().Count();
```

Is there a way to set in the model or somewhere else that the default collection type for a navigation property is an IQueryable or an ObjectQuery or some kind of queryable type?

Note this is only a problem for navigation properties as the actual objectset and dbset items in the context seem to be queryable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with a solution that solves most of my problems. What I ended up doing was using the ObjectContext API and in my model and making the navigation property that was taking a long time to access private (for getting and setting). You can do this in the edmx file by right clicking on the nav property.

Then I made a partial class file for the class that contained the private navigation property and added something along the lines of this.

```
public ObjectQuery<NavPropType> NavPropName
{
   get
   {
      if(privateNavProp != null) //in case lazy loading is disabled or something
         return privateNavProp.CreateSourceQuery();
      else
         return null;
   }
}
```

Now no user of the class can accidentally try to pull in all of the navprop items, which there are a lot of. And it's also easy to make a query on the nav prop instead of having to remember to call CreateSourceQuery every time.

I didn't add a setter because that navigation property is read only in my application. I'm sure there's a way to make one that fits in with this pattern, but I don't know enough about the ObjectContext API to say how to do it.

I only ended up doing this for the navigation properties that could have a ton of data behind them because leaving the other ones as is had no effect on performance.

EDIT: One drawback of making it private that I ran into later is that I could no longer do

```
db.EntryTable.OrderBy(e => e.privateNavProp.Count())
```

even though it would have been smart enough to not get all of the Entities

Comment: does anyone know if CreateSourceQuery is slow enough that it'd be worth it to have a private member of the class that was set on first call to the getter and used in subsequent calls instead of calling CreateSourceQuery every time?

Answer (score 0):

No.  IQueryable is not a collection; IQueryable is an interface whose implementation evaluates queries against a data source (a collection would be the data source).

You could load the count when you load the entity object, however, if inlining some innocuous method calls isn't your thing:

```
from e in EntityA
<optional where clause for entity>
select new
{
    Entity = e,
    filteredNavPropCount = e.navprop.Where( np => <optional where clause for collection> ).Count()
}
```

Comment: While I do find it surprising and annoying that calling count on a navigation property won't do the count in the db, my bigger problem is that people will see that calling count on the nav prop works, and not think anything more of it, even though they are pulling extra data from the db.

Comment: You would use it where you want to filter a nav property collection or aggregate it in some way without retrieve all of the entities from the DB - as you stated in your question.

Comment: ORM's are not about high performance but ease of use.  Nothing will beat the performance of a stored procedure with a custom result set, but that's more coding work.

Comment: wouldn't calling e.navprop.where(whatever).count() get every object in e.navprop from the db though?

Comment: Not in this example b/c the query will evaluate into a SQL statement and execute at the database.